# How to Copy files in FTP path

Tags: file, path, ftp, copy

i have FTP created inside Default FTP Site on one server name A and trying to copy files from other server B and trying to place in Server C through batch script, which is configured in A as physical path,  i can see transfer is happening but its going in root folder of A  which is not correct. Please suggest me what code i need to write in batch script which can place file on sever c.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep directory structure, you can compress to zip with directories and unzip at target. This may also reduce file transfer load. But if you wanna make it one by one, in the batch file, store full path and check full path at target. At target, create full path and copy file if path exists.